# How to unit test winforms applications

Tags: .net, winforms, unit-testing

Thanks to ASP.NET MVC framework, it became possible to unit test web applications. But how do you unit test windows forms applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to use Model View Presenter (MVP) Patterns for Winforms app. Pretty easy to adapt if you already worked with MVC

> Specifically, take the view part of
>   MVC and slice it as thin as possible
>   so that it is only a skin around the
>   actual UI components and make it
>   completely passive. The controller,
>   now called the "presenter," is
>   responsible for all interaction with
>   the rest of the system.

Read some great articles from.

[Dan Bunea - Click to read](http://danbunea.blogspot.com/2005/11/model-view-presenter-is-testing_27.html)

[Jeremy Miller - Click to read](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeremy.miller/articles/129546.aspx)

Happy coding

Comment: Here is a working link to the Jeremy Miller series of blog posts about UI design: http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2007/07/26/the-build-your-own-cab-series-table-of-contents/

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern seems to be the MVP pattern. The test would be executed against a mocked form.

I've also been experimenting with mockable input abstractions and showing the forms while testing. It's easy enough to fill in values in a form as long as popups are out of the way.

In the end the most worthwhile path might be factoring out unit-testable code and just using some UI testing framework for the UI.